# tsyringe - specify which arguments to inject

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, tsyringe

I am using tsyringe to manage my dependency injection. The following code fragment works.

```
import 'reflect-metadata'
import {autoInjectable,singleton} from 'tsyringe'

interface sheepProps {
    legCount: number
}

@singleton()
export class Animal {
  makeSound (sound: string) {
    console.log(sound)
  }
}


@autoInjectable()
class Sheep {

  constructor(sheepProps?: sheepProps, private animal?:Animal) {}

  beeeeh () {
    this.animal.makeSound('bleeeeh')
  }
}

const props: sheepProps = {
    legCount: 4
} 

const sheep = new Sheep(props);
sheep.beeeeh();
```

However when sheepProps is not provided in the call to the constructor by changing `new Sheep(props)` to `new Sheep()`, an error is thrown:

> Error: Cannot inject the dependency "sheepProps" at position #0 of
> "Sheep" constructor. Reason:
> TypeInfo not known for "Object"

To me is seems like tsyringe is trying to inject something when `sheepProps` is not provided in the call to the constructor.

Is this assumption correct, and how would I fix this so I can still use optional arguments in a constructor?

Comment: Because there's no run time value corresponding to the of the first parameter and thus reflect-metadata stores a meaningless toke like `globalThis.Object`. See here for how to register correctly https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe#example-with-interfaces

Comment: @AluanHaddad I think I must be misreading those instructions as I am not getting it to work as I would expect. Could you provide a working solution as an answer?

Comment: I didn't realize initially that the `@autoInjectable()` decorator replaced the class with one having a nullary constructor. I did some experiments and your solution is correct. That is, the combination of applying `@autoInjectable()` to the class and `inject(token)` to any parameters that need explicit registration and lookup behaves as you would expect. I find the idea of this library weird as it requires you to make required arguments optional...

Comment: @AluanHaddad I agree that the chosen method is kind of wierd. Using the DI container should not make it so I must make all other parameters required either. I would had expected something like a decorator that allows me to specify which parameters should be managed by the DI container. However Googling a bit lead me to this library for DI that did not come with a complete framework and is managed by a trusted party.

Comment: You can avoid the problem by making semantically required parameters required `:` not `?:` and always using the container to acquire things. There are alternatives. Consider [`aurelia-dependency-injection`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aurelia-dependency-injection). It works well as a standalone library thanks to its excellent design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code solves the problem, in a way that it is still possible to use `new` to instantiate a class.

Note: Please be aware that when `sheepProps` is not given to the constructor, the value will be an empty object in this case. It is possible to set an other default, however you cannot set it to undefined!

```
import 'reflect-metadata'
import {autoInjectable,singleton, inject, container} from 'tsyringe'

interface SheepProps {
    legCount: number
}

@singleton()
export class Animal {
  makeSound (sound: string) {
    console.log(sound)
  }
}

const sheepPropsToken = Symbol();
container.register(sheepPropsToken, {useValue: {} });

@autoInjectable()
class Sheep {
    private props: SheepProps

  constructor(@inject(sheepPropsToken) sheepProps?: SheepProps, private animal?:Animal) {
    console.log(sheepProps)
    this.props = sheepProps
  }

  beeeeh () {
    this.animal.makeSound('bleeeeh')
  }

  getLegCount() {
    if(this.props.legCount !== undefined) {
        console.log(this.props.legCount)
    } else {
        console.log('Not known to have legs.')
    }
  }
}

const props: SheepProps = {
    legCount: 4
} 

const sheep1 = new Sheep();
sheep1.beeeeh();
sheep1.getLegCount();

const sheep2 = new Sheep(props);
sheep2.beeeeh();
sheep2.getLegCount();
```

Output:

```
{}
bleeeeh
Not known to have legs.
{ legCount: 4 }
bleeeeh
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the following

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import {autoInjectable, container} from 'tsyringe';
import {Animal} from './animal';

interface sheepProps {
  legCount: number;
}

@autoInjectable()
class Sheep {
  constructor(sheepProps?: sheepProps, private animal?: Animal) {}
  beeeeh() {
    this.animal?.makeSound('bleeeeh');
  }
}

const props: sheepProps = {
  legCount: 4
};

const sheep = container.resolve(Sheep);
sheep.beeeeh();
```

As there is no run time value corresponding to the of the first parameter, thus the dependency injection facility provided by `tsyringe` has no meaningful value to correlate with the type of the first parameter. In such a case, the decorator facility will correlate the unhelpful value `globalThis.Object` as can be seen in transpiled output below:

```
var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};
var __metadata = (this && this.__metadata) || function (k, v) {
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.metadata === "function") return Reflect.metadata(k, v);
};
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { autoInjectable, container } from 'tsyringe';
import { Animal } from './animal';
let Sheep = class Sheep {
    animal;
    constructor(sheepProps, animal) {
        this.animal = animal;
    }
    beeeeh() {
        this.animal?.makeSound('bleeeeh');
    }
};
Sheep = __decorate([
    autoInjectable(),
    __metadata("design:paramtypes", [Object, Animal])
], Sheep);
const props = {
    legCount: 4
};
const sheep = container.resolve(Sheep);
sheep.beeeeh();
```

To fix this behavior, we need to use the `tsyringe` API, specifically `container` to register `sheepProps` for injection when a dependent is requested.
*Please note that the decorators like `singleton()` and `autoInjectable()` implicit register the dependencies of decorated constructs and the decorated construct itself such that the container may resolve it.*

**sheep-props.ts**

```
import {container} from 'tsyringe';

export interface sheepProps {
  legCount: number;
}

export const props: sheepProps = {
  legCount: 4
};


export const sheepPropsToken = Symbol();
container.register(sheepPropsToken, {useValue: props});
```

The above registers, `props`, a value of type `sheepProps` with the `container`   under the token `sheepPropsToken` such that it may be resolved by calling `container.resolve(sheepPropsToken)`.

Now back to the `Sheep` class:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import {autoInjectable, container, inject} from 'tsyringe';

import {SheepProps, sheepPropsToken} from './sheep-props';
import {Animal} from './animal';

@autoInjectable()
class Sheep {
  constructor(
    @inject(sheepPropsToken) sheepProps?: SheepProps,
    private animal?: Animal
  ) {}
  beeeeh() {
    this.animal?.makeSound('bleeeeh');
  }
}

const sheep = container.resolve(Sheep);
sheep.beeeeh();
```

The key here is the use of the constructor parameter decorator to specify how the container should lookup `sheepProps` when resolving it to construct `Sheep`. Note that this isn't necessary for the second parameter because there is a value, the `Animal` class itself with which to automatically register and resolve values of type `Animal`.

Here's the relevant difference in the transpiled output:

```
Sheep = __decorate([
    autoInjectable(),
    __param(0, inject(sheepPropsToken)),
    __metadata("design:paramtypes", [Object, Animal])
], Sheep);
const sheep = container.resolve(Sheep);
sheep.beeeeh();
```

The `tsyringe` library's `autoInjectable()` decorator has additional behavior, specifically replacing a decorated class with an equivalent class having a nullary constructor. This is surprising behavior but it allows creation of objects via `new` to use the configured dependency resolution. In other words, `new Sheep()` becomes equivalent to `container.resolve(Sheep)`. This behavior composes with other aspects of the dependency injection system `tsyringe` provides. Wherfor `autoInjectable()` and `inject()`, `container.register`, and other DI related constructs work together. Personally, I find the idea of this awkward and surprising, especially as it requires us to make required arguments optional to avoid TypeScript checker errors. It does however work.

```
const sheep = new Sheep;
sheep.beeeeh();
```

Comment: You are using a variable `props` in `sheep-props.ts` when registering the `sheepPropsToken`. However as the value should be optional. It is unknown if the person instantiating the Sheep class will call it using a SheepProps object or not. As I want to abstract the use of DI away from the person creating a Sheep, this does not feel like a workable solution. They should just be able to call the constructor as `new Sheep()` or `new Sheep({legCount: 4})` instead of `container.resolve(Sheep);`.

Comment: I think I did manage to get a working solution based on your answer. I will post it in my original question. Could you take a look and determine if you see anything wierd?